# Generalising a parameterized query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I've created (with help from StackOverflow!) a reasonably complicated SQL query to perform cohort analysis on how purchasing a particular product affects revenue.

I created it to be parameterized, so that the query can be passed `${PRODUCT}` as the product to evaluate and it'll generate the report.

```
SELECT 
  DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m", month), PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m", earliest_use), MONTH) as nplus,
  CASE WHEN ProductName = '${PRODUCT}' THEN '${PRODUCT}' ELSE 'Other' END as product,
  CustomerInfo,
  AVG(net_revenue) as avg_net_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) as customers
FROM (
SELECT 
  month,
  rev.CustomerID,
  ProductName,
  customers.CustomerInfo,
  SUM(Revenue) AS net_revenue,
  MIN(MIN(CASE WHEN ProductName = '${PRODUCT}' THEN month END)) OVER (PARTITION BY rev.CustomerID) AS earliest_use 
FROM
  RevenueTable as rev,
  CustomerTable AS customers 
WHERE
  customers.CustomerID = rev.CustomerID
  AND rev.CustomerID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
      FROM RevenueTable
      WHERE ProductName = '${PRODUCT}'
    )
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
)
GROUP BY nplus, product, CustomerInfo
HAVING nplus >= -7
ORDER BY nplus
```

However, I now want to **create a generic version that simple iterates this query over ALL products**.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would think you could simply replace the CASE WHEN ProductName... with ProductName and remove the last AND statement in the inner most sub query. You are grouping by product name, so removing the filter by product and grouping by product will produce a list by product.

Comment: If you got help on StackOverflow, how did you end up not using `JOIN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was something I added in afterwards.  TBH, this isn't a production system or anything run regularly. I'm not great with `JOIN`s and tend to make matters worse. Appreciate this isn't the most efficient, but I find it readable. 

Happy to be educated though.

Comment: @RossBush I don't think that'll work, as it also needs to account for the "Other" revenue for each individual product too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CLI to run your [parameterized query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#running_parameterized_queries), you could use an script like:

```
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false  'SELECT product_desc FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.products_list`' | xargs -I {} bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --parameter=product::{} 'SELECT fact_id, product_desc FROM  `PROJECT.DATASET.product_fact_table` WHERE product_desc = @product'
```

In this script, I'm querying the name of the products from a table named "products_list" and then passing each one to the query that get all the operations related to a specific product in the table called "product_fact_table". The result looks like:

[image: script result]

On the other hand, if you are using the API or some of the client libraries (Go, Java, Node.js or Python), I think you only need to build a loop according with the programming language you are using.

The BigQuery UI currently doesn't support parameterized queries.

In addition, I would like to share with you an additional alternative using [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting):

```
DECLARE count INT64 default 0;
DECLARE target_product STRING;
DECLARE products_array ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE number_of_products INT64;

SET number_of_products = (
WITH products AS
  (SELECT ARRAY (select product_desc from `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.products_list`) as products_result)
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(products_result) AS len
FROM products);

SET products_array = (
      SELECT ARRAY_AGG(product_desc)
      FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.products_list`
    ); 

LOOP  
  SET target_product = products_array[OFFSET(count)];
  SELECT * FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.product_fact_table` WHERE product_desc=target_product;
  SET count = count + 1;
  IF count >= number_of_products THEN
    LEAVE;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Here, I'm declaring the "count" variable and using it to count the number of iterations processed, the "target_product" variable  contains the name of the product on each iteration, the "products_array" is set with all the products from a query and, finally, the "number_of_products" contains the total of products and it is used to limit the number of loop iterations.